# Connecting UITextField delegate to File's Owner of Custom Table view cell not working Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have created a View Controller having `UITableView` with custom cell and `xib`. Added a `UITextField` in custom cell xib. Now I have connected the delegate of `UITexField` to the File's Owner of custom cell xib and in the View controller I have added below code :

```
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      textField.endEditing(true)
      return true
  }

}
```

Above method is not getting called.

It work's if I add below code in `cellForRowAtindexPath` :

```
cell.myTextField.delegate = self
```

Can someone help me, why connecting the `UITextField` delegate to File's owner in custom cell not working.

**EDIT**

I am registering nib like this:

```
myTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycustomcellreuseidentifier")
```

and in `cellForRowAtindexPath`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycustomcellreuseidentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
```

I haven't added any code in `MyCustomTableViewCell` except the `@IBOutlet` for `UITextField`.

**Edit** - with the help of @Puneet Sharma and @Francesco Deliro

Tried below code:

```
let myCustomCellNib = UINib(nibName: "MyCustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
myCustomCellNib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)

myTableView.register(myCustomCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycustomcellreuseidentifier")
```

and as @Puneet Sharma suggested to change the File's Owner inside nib. I did below change in Identity inspector by adding the class name to `MyViewController`:

[image]

Still not working.

Should I go with:

```
cell.myTextField.delegate = self
```

in `cellForRowAtindexPath`.

Comment: After doing this did you create a connection on your textfield delegate property to File Owner?

Comment: Yes I did that too.

Comment: Save your nib file by pressing command+S, and try agian.

Comment: @PuneetSharma - Did that. I in-fact tried quitting the xcode too.

Comment: I have mentioned it above.

Comment: Let me check this on a sample project. Theoretically it should work. Also, if you can upload your project on web, I can take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157341/discussion-between-amit-and-puneet-sharma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have never set the owner of the nib to your MyViewController.

You must be calling `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` in your `MyViewController` class, where you are providing the `UINib` object.

You must have created this `UINib` object, by calling `init(nibName:bundle:)`. There, you have not provided the owner of this nib as `MyViewController`.

About [FileOwner](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html), this is from Apple's documentation:

> File’s Owner object is a placeholder object that is not created when
>   the nib file is loaded. Instead, you create this object in your code
>   and pass it to the nib-loading code.

In case of UIViewController nib/storyboard, FileOwner is already set by XCode template so you can make direct IBOutlet connections.
 
In case of your custom tableviewCell, the fileowner needs to be provided through code.

<del>This can be done using [instantiate(withOwner:options:)][2] method on nib object (I have shamelessly copied the code from Fransesco's answer above).</del>

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil) 
nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil) 
myTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycustomcellreuseidentifier")
```

Earlier, I thought the fileowner can be set using UINib method of [instantiate(withOwner:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinib/1614137-instantiate) method, but although this method is for setting the nib owner, it does not work in case of `tableview.register(nib:)` method.

This is perhaps, because when tableview tries to dequeue the cell for the first time and it does not find one, it creates the cell from the registered nib but set its owner as nil. I have not found the official doc supporting this, but this is what is perhaps happening which is resulting in issues in the sample project.

I have removed the registerNib code from the sample, and created the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, and this worked.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycellreuseidentifier") as? MyTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        let array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        cell = array!.first as! MyTableViewCell
    }
    return cell!
}
```

This alone, though is not enough. You have to change the File Owner inside nib as `MyViewController`. This is to be done in Identity inspector tab for the nib. Just set MyViewController as the FileOwner.

Although, this worked, but I guess if you need to write this much in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, its better you set delegate there itself as you have done in your commented code.

Comment: I understand the first three lines but I din't get the last two. I have edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: @Amit: Edited the answer. Hope it clears your doubts.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried what you suggested but still not working.

Comment: I have uploaded the project on git - https://github.com/meet0226/SampleTextField .

Comment: @Amit: I looked at the sample project and found out the issues. Correcting the answer with details.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, help and time. I am accepting your answer as it worked , but I will go with setting delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @Amit: Glad to help Amit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In `cell.myTextField.delegate = self` self is your `UIViewController`, that is connected with the delegate `MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate`.
If you have made the connection in your cell xib your reference is the cell. So if you want that your connection works there you have to set the connection with the cell `MyCell: UITextFieldDelegate`.

**Edit:**
If you want to use your delegate in your ViewController you have to follow Puneet answer in this way:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
_ = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] 
myTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mycustomcellreuseidentifier")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want my connection to work in `MyViewController` not in `MyCell`.

Comment: You are welcome, I have edited my answer you can check it.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried what you suggested but still not working. I have edited the question.

Comment: Sorry I have never used this approach! My mistake, I have edited again my answer ;)

Comment: I think this code is not appropriate as `myTableView.register` method can not be invoked with an argument list of type custom cell.

Comment: If you remove the cast with your cell? Usually I connect the delegate with my cell and use closure to communicate with my view controller